# .net session clears php session

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, php, asp.net-session

I have a very strange situation on a website where a .net session seems to be clearing a php session.

When a user logs into the site, the .net session is created, and then the code then calls a php page which sets the php session. This set up has worked on many sites, but yet a new site in develoment just wont work.

If the php session is set directly, it works, but then when a .net session is created the php session is removed.

The website is running on IIS7.

The code:

vb

```
Session("username") = "username"
```

php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = "username";
```

I then check on another page

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['username'] ))
```

There is nothing else in the code that would be clearing any sessions.
Has anyone ever experienced this? Is there a setting somewhere which could cause this in IIS7?

Answer (score 0):

OK, a couple of quick questions:

- You're running both PHP and ASP.net code on the same IIS7 Server with the same domain name?
- by "and then the code then calls a php page which sets the php session" do you mean you redirect the browser to a php page?

Sessions usually work via cookies so a good place to start would be to look at the browser cookies after each step. I'd expect to see two cookies - one for the asp.net session and another for the php session.

Comment: Yeah both PHP and ASP.net code on the same IIS7 same domain. It is a redirect from asp.net page to php page then back to asp.net or php page. All the cookies are being set correctly and can be seen. But when the .net session is set, the php one is lost. Very strange